# Отправка данных из БД пользователю через телеграм-бот

Tags: telegram-bot

Пишу десктопное приложение с локальной БД (SQLite3). Есть идея использовать тг-бота для отправки отчетности пользователям-администраторам по их запросу. Планируется, что готовое ПО будет распространено в разных компаниях, т.е у каждой будут свои данные в БД, но конечный алгоритм генерации отчетности один. Суть вопроса - как сделать так, чтобы при обращении к боту, каждый пользователь получал ответ именно по своим данным в бд, чтобы не было конфликтов? Я новичок в деле написания ботов, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, может не столько готовые решения, а что прочесть по этому поводу.

Comment: _Что прочесть_ — очевидно, книги по SQLite3. А решение вашего вопроса без кода вряд ли возможно.